# Check if a Binary Tree is Balanced or not

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-tree

I tried to solve this question in LeetCode, even though my solution was right, one particular test case has failed.

My Code :

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution(object):
    def isBalanced(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        
        #height,flag = self.dfs(root)
        
        return self.dfs(root)[1]
    
    def dfs(self,node,isTreeBalanced=True):
        
        if node is None or not isTreeBalanced:
            return 0,isTreeBalanced
        
        leftHeight , isTreeBalanced = self.dfs(node.left,isTreeBalanced)
        rightHeight, isTreeBalanaced = self.dfs(node.right,isTreeBalanced)
        print(abs(leftHeight-rightHeight))
        
        
        if abs(leftHeight - rightHeight) > 1:
            isTreeBalanced = False
        
        
        
        return max(leftHeight,rightHeight)+1 , isTreeBalanced
```

Test Case Input for which my Code failed:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,null,6,7,null,null,null,null,8]
```

Leetcode question : [Check if the Tree is Balanced or not](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/)

Can anyone help in identifying the issue? Is there any edge case I am missing ?

Comment: There is a typo in `isTreeBalanaced` when you're checking the `right` child.

Comment: The test case data doesn't look right.  It looks like the parent of "8" is a null node, which I don't believe is allowed.  Are you sure you didn't miss a "null" somewhere?

Comment: `isTreeBalanaced = self.dfs(node.right,isTreeBalanced)` This part should be changed to `isTreeBalanced = self.dfs(node.right,isTreeBalanced)`

Comment: @aminrd Good catch.  I think that's all that's needed to fix it, since it passes the new value of `isTreeBalanced` to the second recursive call, so once it's `False`, it should stay `False`.  The test data still looks wrong, but that should fix the code.

Comment: @RageshKr In case you didn't see it, aminrd pointed out that you mistyped `isTreeBalanced` in one place. It has an extra `a` in it, i.e. `isTreeBalanaced` instead of `isTreeBalanced`.  You just need to fix the typo by deleting the extra `a`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks a lot for pointing it out! My bad , sorry for wasting ur time on a typo. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and you have not missed any testcase, it is just that you have misspelled the isTreeBalanced as **isTreeBalanaced** which is why you were getting the testcase failed which was having only nodes on left and just one node on right.

Although I solved this entire question and here is my code for the above question:

```
class Solution:
        
    def isBalanced(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        self.Balanced = True
        if not root:
            return self.Balanced
        self.maxDepth(root)
        return self.Balanced
    
    def maxDepth(self, root):
        if not root:
            return 0
        else:
            ldepth = self.maxDepth(root.left)
            rdepth = self.maxDepth(root.right)
            if abs(ldepth - rdepth) >= 2:
                self.Balanced = False
            return max(ldepth, rdepth) + 1
```

Time Complexity : O(N)
Space Complexity : O(N) (For call stack)

Comment: I not calling isBalaned I am calling maxDepth so initializing it won't effect it, If you are talking about something else then please let me know i will accept any feedback

Comment: If you see I am already setting **self.Balanced to False** in the else part and the isBalanced method you are talking about is used to return the final value which is updated to self.Balanced and finally returning it .

Comment: That's why I have used self right it will be updated with the current instance once it is true it will be updated to true else false and will return it if you want to try u can try that I tried with different testcases and it was giving me correct according to what I am returning . Can you mention any testcase where my code will fail ?

Comment: I can understand your point but I am not using isBalanced to make my recursive call so it won't effect . I hope this helps

Comment: So do you think my code will not work ?? I have checked it and it is working fine you can also try that to remove your confusion.

Comment: Hey @TomKarzes  sorry I was misunderstood as that this code is wrong , and it passed the testcase on the Leetcode platform so i was in a dilemma that why I didn't run on it my local system and when I ran now i got your point it needs to set to true again to start with.

Comment: It is fixed now as you told, thanks for clarifying **how can i connect with you with over any platform** . Sorry for the resilience shown I was stupid i didn't check it on my local.

Comment: Yup , now it's been fixed

Comment: Yes, I believe it should work now.  Note that the `if not root:` test is not needed in `isBalanced`, since it's already covered in `maxDepth`.